# Laravel query building with variables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Assume that i have variables like $var1 and $var2.

Assume that i want to have a query like

```
$myQuery = DB::table('myTable')
           ->where('firstField', '=', $var1)
           ->where('secondField', '=', $var2)
           ->get();
```

Of course this one doesn't work when my variables are null. I want to control them, and do something if they are null.

I should create a query based on those variables and filter them with the values they hold.

Any other ideas how to do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
$results = DB::table('myTable')->where(function($query) use ($var1, $var2) {
               if ( ! empty($var1)) {
                   $query->where('firstField', '=', $var1);
               }
               if ( ! empty($var2)) {
                   $query->where('secondField', '=', $var2);
               }
           })->get();
```

Edit: Corrected ::where to ->where

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you want but you can easily build a query in multiple "steps" using conditionals:

```
$query = DB::table('myTable');

if($var1 !== null){
    $query->where('firstField', $var1);
}
if($var2 !== null){
    $query->where('secondField', $var2);
}

$result = $query->get();
```

Comment: this might be a solution too, but that doesn't work in my case. I join tables. Also there's a syntax error out there like 'firstField', '$var1' should be 'firstField', '=', $var1 but thank you for giving me ideas anyway.

Comment: Well in your question there is no join... And I don't see why this shouldn't work with joins. Also `=` can be omitted

Answer (score 1):

For example you can make like this:

```
$myQuery = DB::table('myTable')
       ->where('firstField', '=', is_null($var1)?0:$var1)
       ->where('secondField', '=', is_null($var2)?0:$var2)
       ->get();
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation?

Comment: blankBird_ said its code doesn't work if those vars are null. Its means that you can check it, and if it are null you can find in table 0 or, for example 'null'.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to explain the ternary logic you're using, some people may be unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Ok, its like simple 'if-else', but in srort form. Syntax is simple: echo (condition == 0) ? "do something if true" :  "do somsing if false";

Comment: You can edit your answer to elaborate or make it clearer. No need to restrict yourself to comments.